# Displaying a list inside list by AngularJS inside html table

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to display months just beside each Quarter

> (Q1(1st td) Jan(2nd td) Feb(3rd td) Mar(4th td) Q2(5th td) Apr(6th td).....till Dec where all the data is available in CodPeriodDetails(which will carry Quarter details) & in each Quarter 3 months will be available in QMDtls). Please refer link to know how the data is binding:

```
<tr class="height_25">
    <th data-ng-repeat="data in CODperiodData" data-ng-if="(data.PT==0 || data.PT==4)" colspan="2">
        <span>{{data.PD}}</span>
    </th>                             
    <th data-ng-repeat="d in data.QMdtls" colspan="2">
        <span>{{d.PD}}</span>
    </th>
</tr>
```

JS_Snippet

[image]

Comment: You want to add <table> <th> main heading <th> sub heading</th></th> </table>?

Comment: Actually I need to display data inside CODperiodData in a single tr along with data inside QMdtls(values of QMdtls will be present in each row of CODperiodData). So as I explained the final output need to be displayed like:

Q1(a row in CODperiodData) Jan(a row in QMdtls which resides in CODperiodData) Feb(a row in QMdtls which resides in CODperiodData) Mar(a row in QMdtls which resides in CODperiodData) ..........

hope this helps.

Comment: For a layout this complex it might be better to build out your data structure in the controller instead of trying to do this all in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried implementing the logic in controller but this is the best possible output I can get. Is there a way to bind the list in html using index like "data in CODperiodData[$index].QMdtls" where the QMdtls list can be looped on its own without looping CODperiodData list first